# Find a key in a file and output the corresponding value

Tags: bash

I have a file `file1.txt` with the following content

```
P0000021=Result of string 21
P0000022=Result of string 22
P0000023=Result of string 23
P0000024=Result of string 24
P0000025=Result of string 25
P0000026=Result of string 26
P0000027=Result of string 27
T1000028=Result of string 28
```

and want to use some command to find a arbitrary key and get the corresponding value. E.g. if I search for `P0000024` the output should be

```
Result of string 24
```

I tried using `grep` like this:

```
grep '"P0000024"=' file1.txt | cut -d'=' -f2 > result.txt
```

However it does not give the expected result.

Comment: without a doubt, the correct tool for this job is awk or sed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk -F= -v x="P0000024" '$1==x{print $2}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

remove double quotes from grep expression

```
grep 'P0000024=' file1.txt | cut -d'=' -f2 > result.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -n '/P0000024=/{s///;p;q}' file
```